# Packaging F# program for Mono

Tags: f#, mono, packaging

I am currently learning F# and preparing to write my first program. I will be using Visual Studio 10 in Windows 7 to write the code, because the F# support for MonoDevelop is a few versions behind.

My normal day-to-day development environment is Mac Os X 10.7. I have Mono and MonoDevelop installed. After I finish writing my masterpiece, how do I package it for running on Os X? What DLLs do I need to send to other Windows users so that they can run my .exe file? How do they install those DLLs?

In the Java world (where I usually live), I just package my Java code with any dependencies into a monolithic **UberJAR** that I can send to anyone who has the appropriate version of Java (usually 6) and they can run my code by typing

```
java -jar MyUberJar.jar
```

I routinely write code in Scala and include the Scala library, along with any other dependencies.

Is there any easy way to do something similar for .NET, and specifically for F#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative is to use the `--standalone` flag to `fsc` which will statically compile all the DLL's you need into a single large EXE.  The people you send it to will still need to install Mono, but there are no other dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what most people use:

http://wix.sourceforge.net/

I say "I think" because at work we've got a release team that builds the installer package for us.